# Do Page Events Add to the Value of PageViews?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a page with Events. I know that when the Events fire, this adds to the Bounce rate. I have noticed that page views have gone up also. Are Events counted as PageViews or is it just coincidence?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they are two different things counted separately. Check that the page does not refresh or that you have 2 times the Analytics code on the page.